# Display text string without \

Tags: php

I realize this is just about as simple a question as you can get, but I can't seem to find the answer.

```
echo $textstring;
```

OUTPUT LOOKS LIKE THIS:

The quotes don\'t work, \"because this text field is trying to make quotes that will show up properly when put between \' and \', but I don\'t want that.\"

BUT I WANT:

The quotes don't work, "because this text field is trying to make quotes that will show up properly when put between ' and ', but I don't want that."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it's your server setting - in php.ini, look for [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)

Answer (score 4):

Disable magic quotes in your `php.ini` unless you want to spend your life using `stripslashes`. Make sure the following settings in `php.ini` are as following:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

You can also disable by putting the following in your `.htaccess`:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo stripslashes($textstring);
```

Comment: This should not be necessary, the OP should disable magic quotes.

Comment: He may not want to do that server wide and he may not have the ability to edit the php.ini file either.

Comment: That was what I needed. Thanks! Though it would good for me to learn how to disable magic quotes, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stripslashes()` function like so:

```
echo stripslashes($textstring);
```

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use the `stripslashes` function:

```
echo stripslashes($textstring);
```

This will remove all slashes.